# Get the minimum number out of a file and print. Python

Tags: python, eclipse, list, min

I have run into a problem with my Python program.
I am trying to get a list from the file and print the lowest number.
eg.

```
showFile = open("company.txt", 'r')
        for line in showFile:
            tokens = line.split(',')
            minValue = min(tokens[:2])
            print("the lowest is", minValue)
```

and it outputs-

```
the lowest is  33
the lowest is  18.5
the lowest is  22
```

Here is the company.txt -

```
'Huggies', 33, 84
'Snugglers', 18.5, 72
'Baby Love', 22, 96
```

I am quite nooby, so any help would be awesome.

Comment: What do you want the program to do? Please add what you think the ideal output would be.

Comment: Be careful about comparing strings when you really want numbers. Although 100 is greater than 2, "100" is less than "2" because it only checks the first character. Your company.txt file just happens to work because the first digit is in the right order. Add some other cases such as `'Pooper Scooper', 100, 2` and `'999 Things', 44, 16` to the file to make sure you get the math right.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're finding the lowest number separately in each line. Sort of. If you want the lowest single number in the file, you should collect the numbers or the minimum number from each line into a single list, and call min() on that list outside the for loop.

Another problem, though, is the way you're checking the numbers with `tokens[:2]`. Stick a `print tokens` statement after this and you'll find that you're cutting off the second number of each line. If the goal was to cut off the company name, you'd use [1:]. This is the problem with the other answers that retain this `tokens[:2]` line. They appear to work, but only because the lowest number happens to be in the first column. Calling `min(tokens[1:])` also evaluates the number as a string which may produce unexpected results and still includes whitespace, like `' 18.5\n'`. To compare the numbers as numbers, wrap them in float().

Altogether, something like this:

```
showFile = open("company.txt", 'r')
numbers = []
for line in showFile:
    tokens = line.split(',')
    numbers.append(min(float(t) for t in tokens[1:]))

minValue = min(numbers)
print("the lowest is ", minValue)
```

Comment: you need to cast the tokens to float before the 'min' operation otherwise you are taking the min of the token strings instead of the token values: `numbers.append(min(float(tokens[1:])))`

Comment: The alternative you give doesn't quite work, because calling float() on a list raises an error. But `numbers.append(min(float(t) for t in tokens[1:]))` seems to work, provided that all tokens can be cast to floats.

Comment: with this im still getting the output of
the lowest is 33.0
the lowest is 18.5
the lowest is 18.5
is there a way to only get the 1 lowest?

Comment: When I run the above I get 18.5. Just copying and pasting into a new file. If you're using this verbatim and still getting something different, maybe something is working differently between Python 2 and 3..?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is get the lowest value of the entire file, and not for each line, then just do the following:

```
myLowNumbers = []
showFile = open("company.txt", 'r')
        for line in showFile:
            tokens = line.split(',')
            minValue = min(tokens[:2])
            myLowNumbers.append(minValue)
print min(myLowNumbers)
```

This will continue to add the lowest number from each line to a list, and then return the lowest value from the list once the loop is done.  There are certainly more elegant ways to doing this, but until more information is provided, this is the best I can offer.

**BTW, don't forget to <strike>pay tribute</strike> approve of the correct answer by 'up-voting' the correct answers** - welcome to SO.

Comment: "Paying tribute" isn't the term I'd really use here ;-).

Comment: lol no, not in the sense of sacrificing a lamb on an alter.  If that is what he want's to offer, then I kindly reject.  =P

Answer (score 0):

You're not really comparing any of the numbers to each other.

This isn't super elegant, but it works.

```
showFile = open("company.txt", 'r')
lowest = None
for line in showFile:
    tokens = line.split(',')
    value = min(tokens[:2])
    if lowest == None: 
        lowest = value #set lowest value to first number found
    if value < lowest:
        lowest = value

print("the lowest is", lowest)
```

(also I think you're using Python 3.x, I'm using 2.6, just a heads up incase something doesn't quite line up)